# Multiple insert for each one column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables i want my code making insert from each one column i have in first Table. Here is my code:

```
insert into Inventory (InventoryItemID,ID) 
select 
       inventoryitemid,
      (select MAX(id)+1 from Inventory) 
from Inventory_Panel 
where InventoryItemID 
IN 
(
    select InventoryItemID 
    from InventoryBarCodes 
    WHERE BarCode IN (SELECT BarCode FROM Market)
)
```

I get error:Msg 2627,Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Inventory'.

Comment: Your InventoryItemID column is primary key?

Comment: No 'id' is the primarykey.As i can understand it cant run Max(id)+1 for each insert.

Comment: `InventoryItemID` is either a `primary` or `unique` key.That's why it's not allowing you duplicate values.

Comment: Why not you set identity column to Id

Comment: run your query without the insert and you will see that max(id) + 1 is the same for each record. Either make ID an identity field or do this in a loop with a cursor

Comment: Cause in my case i cant change it in identity from management studio.Can i change it to identity only in specific insert?

Comment: why not, do you get any errors ?

Comment: @GuidoG OP has already find the issue

Comment: Now only way to replace function which return max id with select MAX(id)+1 from Inventory

Comment: Cant run my code as loop?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it in a loop like this :

```
declare @InventoryItemID int
declare @ID int

declare crInventoryPanel Cursor local fast_forward for
  select inventoryitemid
  from Inventory_Panel 
  where InventoryItemID IN ( select InventoryItemID 
                             from InventoryBarCodes 
                             WHERE BarCode IN (SELECT BarCode FROM Market)
                           )                        
open crInventoryPanel
fetch next from crInventoryPanel into @InventoryItemID
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    select @ID = max(ID) + 1 from Inventory

    insert into Inventory (InventoryItemID, ID)
    values (@InventoryItemID, @ID)

    fetch next from crInventoryPanel into @InventoryItemID
end
close crInventoryPanel
deallocate crInventoryPanel
```

Comment: OR Can i change ID to auto increment only for this insert and disable auto increment when it will finished? ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype, something like that

Comment: I belief it is not possible to alter an existing column to identity

Comment: You would have to create a new table with the same columns and a temp name, but your ID as identity. Copy over your data using identity_insert. Then drop your old table and rename the new one.

Comment: something like that ALTER TABLE inventory
ALTER COLUMN id int auto_increment

Comment: No you cannot do that, the only way is like @Jens said. Either do that or use the loop from my answer.

Comment: @DiH I updated my answer there was an error in the declaration of the cursor

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tTemp TABLE(
Id int IDENTITY(1, 1)
, InventoryItemId int)
```

Next insert your values into this temporary table variable and use the id in the temporary table add the max id of the Inventory table to calculate the value to insert into your table.

Comment: you could also use the max id of the Inventory Table to initialize the identity